# jQuery Validation plugin display success/fail images next to password

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery form validation using validation plugin.
 I have validate the password with minimum 7 characters and one capital and oe number.at the same time when i meet that the password is valid need to show the correct image near to the textfield. Otherwise wrong image.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('mypassword', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value.match(/[A-Z]/) && value.match(/[0-9]/));
    },
    'Password must contain at least one capital and one number.');


    jQuery("#loanRequestDetailsForm").validate({
        ignore: "",
        rules : {

        password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                mypassword :true
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }


        },
        messages : {

            password : {
                required:"Please provide a password",
                minlength:"Your password must be at least 7 characters long"    
            },  
            confirmpassword : {
                required:"Please provide a password",
                minlength:"Your password must be at least 7 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }


        }
    });
```

Any idea to display the image

Comment: You should show your form's HTML if you want an answer that contains a specific working demo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a combination of [`errorPlacement`, `success`, `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) along with CSS `class`'s.  The following seems very verbose, but it's in order 
to only display the images next to the password fields.  It could be simplified greatly if you wanted to display the images next to *all* fields instead.

**CSS**:

```
.passError {
    background: url("bad.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
.passValid {
    background: url("good.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class="pw" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="text" class="pw" name="confirmpassword" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('mypassword', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value.match(/[A-Z]/) && value.match(/[0-9]/));
    }, 'Password must contain at least one capital and one number.');

    $('#loanRequestDetailsForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            if (element.hasClass('pw')) {
                element.next().removeClass('passValid').addClass('passError');
            }
        },
        success: function (label) {
            if (label.prev().hasClass('pw')) {
                label.text("ok!");
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if ($(element).hasClass('pw')) {
                $(element).next().removeClass('passValid').addClass('passError');
            } else {
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if ($(element).hasClass('pw')) {
                $(element).next().removeClass('passError').addClass('passValid');
            } else {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                mypassword: true
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 7, // <- redundant
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                // use the placeholder {0} to automatically insert rule val
                minlength: "Your password must be at least {0} characters long"
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/jtmDY/**

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice example of using an image when displaying the error here

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-methods-demo.html

It uses this css to how an image for the error

```
em.error {
  background:url("images/unchecked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

note this example has set

```
errorElement: "em"
```

so the css works, but look through the source and try it out

Comment: but i need to add image only for password field not other fields

Comment: I'd still use css - what about adding a class 'passwordimage' to the fields you want a picture on and using this selector 'em.error.passwordimage'