# how to add error icon and custom validation message using jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I Would like to add error icon and custom validation message using jQuery Validate plugin. Like this

[image]

Here is my html code,

```
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="required" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="required" /> <br>

    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="required" /> <br>
```

Here is my Html code,

I have tried with errorPlacement function, however for some reason i am not able to get error message below the control. I have used prepentTo, appendTo, all jquery function to do this. but no luck!!!

```
function validateForm(){
           
            $("#register").validate({
               
               
                rules: {
                    firstName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    }
                },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        error.insertAfter(element); 
                            
                    },
                    
            });
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on your code, you are using the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin, not the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin.  These are two different things and you should be more careful when tagging your questions.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for some reason i am not able to get error message below the control.

By default, the error message is put inside a `label` which is an inline element.

Use [the `errorElement` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to change this into a block level element and it will wrap automatically.

**See:  http://jsfiddle.net/kH9NL/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ 
        errorElement: "div",
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

You must use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions to manipulate the placement and toggling of your icons.

This answer provides a concrete example using these two callback functions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14900826/594235

Comment: Wow! that is greate help, thanks. still lot of work is left in this. like placing icon

Comment: @niran, See this answer for help with that.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14900826/594235

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) of options you can pass to validate function

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
}
```

so your code should be:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  error.appendTo(element.parent()); 
}
```

or something like these.

Then you can use **wrapper** property to specify a container for your errors.

Moreover you can use **errorClass** property to change error class.

And you can use **messages** property to set custom message.

Then you have to specify rules for the selector you choose.

You can take a look also [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Hope this helps